# Setting a control name with concatenated text+variable for ControlSetText usage

Tags: autohotkey

TL;DR  I created a new variable (destinationControl) by concatenating a string, a separate string variable, and then another string. I tried using the variable destinationControl with ControlSetText, but its not working. Can anyone tell me why?

Long Explanation:
I'm attempting to send some data from an excel spreadsheet into another application using AHK ControlSetText. My issue comes in when I need the script to detect which one of two possible programs is the active one (the detection part is working) and then based on the name of the program, set the destination control name is slightly different.

```
prog_A_segment := "abc"
prog_B_segment := "def"

;determine which program is open
IfInString, OpenProgram, ProgA
{
    ctrlSegment := prog_A_segment
}
else
    ctrlSegment := prog_B_segment

;set control variable
destinationControl := "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0." . ctrlSegment . "_r13_ad11"

;activate program
WinActivate, % OpenProgram
WinWaitActive, % OpenProgram,,3

;open vendor form
Sleep 300
Send ^o
Sleep 200
Send Vendors
sleep 200
Send {ENTER}
Sleep 2000

;This does not work:
;pass information to vendor form control
ControlSetText, %destinationControl%, %myNumber%, %OpenProgram%
```

I know I could just slightly more manually set them based on the open program but i have about 25 controls in total and the only difference is that center segment so I thought this would be a little more elegant and cleaner.

When I use the above method it doesn't appear AHK can find the control. I'm assuming it has something to do with how I combined a string and a variable. Is there some way to make this approach work without doing this instead:

```
IfInString, OpenProgram, ProgA
{
    destinationControl1 := "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.abc_r13_ad11"
    ....
    destinationControl25 := "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.abc_d52_ad11"
}
else
    destinationControl1 := "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.def_r13_ad11"
    ....
    destinationControl25 := "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.def_d52_ad11"
```

Comment: "Is there some way to..."
Apparently.
But exactly what you're trying to do with your code is unclear, especially the connection between `destinationControl` and `vendorCtrl`.

Comment: sorry about that, fixed. They were both supposed to be destinationControl.

The goal is just use ControlSetText using the variable destinationControl. This variable is set by concatenating a string, variable, then another string. For some reason ControlSetText will not work with the new concatenated variable (destinationControl).

Comment: Not sure if this is the case in your full script, but in the code you posted the `destinationControl` assignment is missing a quote at the end. Other than that it looks like it should work (as long as you've confirmed that the 25-assignment version works). Maybe post the full code between the assignment and `ControlSetText`?

Comment: Yep, the missing quote was just a typo. But theres not much more code between assignment and ControlSetText, but I've updated the original post to include everything.

Comment: I figured it out. Completely unrelated to my code. The program (an ERP system), changes a small segment of it's the ClassNN name each time I open it. Possibly based on which i've opened first or something like that. Since I can't be sure what CtrlSegment will be each time I had it look for a small string right before and after it that remain consistent 
  
  
`ctrlSegment = % SubStr(SubStr(ControlName,InStr(ControlName,"app.0.")+6),1,InStr( 
 
SubStr(ControlName,InStr(ControlName,"app.0.")+6),"_")-1)`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Josh Brobst that your first piece of code would work with the missing quote added.

Well, here's what you want to try anyways:

```
ctrlSegment := InStr(OpenProgram, ProgA) ? "abc" : "def"

Loop Parse, % "r13, ... ,d52", CSV
    ControlSetText % "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0." ctrlSegment "_" A_LoopField "_ad11"
        , % myNumber, % OpenProgram
```